# In Puma, how do I calculate DB connections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I'm trying to figure out how many database connections my app will use.

It's Rails 5 hosted on Heroku.

Here is my Puma config

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

And the first part of my DB config:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5 %>
```

The part that seems strange to me is # of connections, and also my `pool` setting in `database.yml` are all using `RAILS_MAX_THREADS`... but shouldn't it be using `RAILS_MAX_THREADS` multiplied by the number of workers (`WEB_CONCURRENCY`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually I found the answer explained well here... https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#database-connections

---

As you add more concurrency to your application, it will need more connections to your database. A good formula for determining the number of connections each application will require is to multiply the `RAILS_MAX_THREADS` by the `WEB_CONCURRENCY`. This combination will determine the number of connections each dyno will consume.

Rails maintains its database connection pool, with a new pool created for each worker process. Threads within a worker will operate on the same pool. Make sure there are enough connections inside of your Rails database connection pool so that `RAILS_MAX_THREADS` number of connections can be used. If you see this error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError - could not obtain a database connection within 5 seconds
```

This error is an indication that your Rails connection pool is too low. For an in-depth look at these topics, please read the Dev Center article [Concurrency and Database Connections](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#threaded-servers).